# How to detect version on Webpack in Node.js API?

Tags: webpack

Is there a way to detect the version on Webpack being used in from inside a Node.js script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to execute and parse Linux command output:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
// if webpack is installed locally, remove --global flag
var cliCommand = "npm ls webpack --global=true --json=true";

exec(cliCommand, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  if (stderr) {
    console.log('ERR' + stderr);
  }
  else if (stdout) {
    console.log('webpack version: ' + JSON.parse(stdout).dependencies.webpack.version);      
})
```

please note that `exec` function uses asynchronous callback, so result is not printed immediately

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a package called [`listver`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/listver).